# Converting hex to binary

Tags: binary, hex

How can I Convert these **binary input** into **hex values**. Using **python 3**:

```
11111000 10011011

01101101 10011101

11100001 01111011

11000001 00010111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can do something like:

```
a = "11111000 10011011 01101101 10011101 11100001 01111011 11000001 00010111"
a = a.replace(" ", "")
i = int(a, 2)
print(hex(i))
```

A one-liner would be:

```
print(hex(int("11111000 10011011 01101101 10011101 11100001 01111011 11000001 00010111".replace(" ", ""), 2)))
```